# SP task list data push to SQL

Tags: list, event-receivers, sql-server, sql, datasheet

What is my option so my sp task list still push the data to our sql database using the datasheet view? I was told that adding new item to the list triggers an event handler which uploads the data from SharePoint to DB. 
Recently, I had to go away from doing the manual addition of item to the list. I need to use the datasheet so I can paste multiple rows from excel to my sp list. but the trigger is no longer working and so SP stopped pushing data to our sql database. how do I counter that? what should we do to adjust the trigger?

Thanks,
Rolly

Comment: pls include the SharePoint version as well.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you might have implemented a custom event handler based on your own logic to update the external SQL database tables with synchronous or asynchronous events.

Also, first see whether the event receiver is firing or not for this just implement a dummy file creation or updating another SharePoint list item as a sample.

As a further trouble shooting step, make sure you implement the logging so you can trace the problems with the exceptions in the logic if any.

I hope backward compatibility for the event receivers is enabled at the web application level and you haven't migrated/upgraded the site collection or web applications b/w SharePoint versions.

Comment: the event is hiring if I will do the Add Item from Sharepoint. I tried that already.